# How to save a struct to NSUserDefaults in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, struct, nsuserdefaults

How do I save a custom `struct` to `NSUserDefaults`?

```
struct Paging {
    NSInteger currentPage;
    NSInteger totalResults;
    NSInteger resultsPerPage;
};

typedef struct Paging Paging;

NSUserDefaults *userInfo = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userInfo setStruct:paging forKey:@"paging"];
[userInfo synchronize];
```

The above code produces a run-time warning:
`*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value...`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One way is to turn it into NSData

```
NSData* d = [NSData dataWithBytes: paging length: sizeof(paging)];
```

In this case your struct is pretty simple, so you might want to add a category to NSUserDefaults to save and restore it. I'd implement that by saving an NSDictionary with four NSNumbers. A bit more work, but it means your plist will be humanly readable.

Comment: This potentially dangerous, depending on the contents of the `struct`. See chown's answer for details. Between 32-bit and 64-bit architectures, the layout of the struct is very likely to be different. You can add the `__attribute__((packed))` compiler directive to force the compiler to remove any padding that it would otherwise add to make the fields align with the native architecture.

Comment: True, though I don’t think it is any safer if you pad the struct.

Answer (score 5):

In your specific case, you can get away with using an `NSData` since the members are just `int`s, but for future readers of this question, please read the Apple docs on *[Encoding and Decoding C Data Types](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html)* before doing this!

**[Encoding and Decoding C Data Types - Structures and Bit Fields](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html):**

> You should **not** wrap a structure with an `NSData` object and archive
>   that. If the structure contains object or pointer fields, the data
>   object **isn’t going to archive them correctly**. You also create a
>   dependence on how the compiler decides to lay out the structure, which
>   can change between versions of the compiler and may depend on other
>   factors. *A compiler is not constrained to organize a structure just as
>   you’ve specified it in the source code—there may be arbitrary internal
>   and invisible padding bytes between fields in the structure*, for
>   example, and the amount of these can change without notice and on
>   different platforms. In addition, any fields that are multiple bytes
>   in width **aren’t going to get treated correctly** with respect to
>   endianness issues. **You will cause yourself all sorts of compatibility
>   trouble.**

That doc does say how to properly do it (but no examples are given unfortunately - when I come up with one however, I will update this answer with the example):

> The best technique for archiving a structure or a collection of bit
>   fields is to **archive the fields independently** and chose the
>   *appropriate type of encoding/decoding method for **each***. The key names
>   can be composed from the structure field names if you wish, like
>   `"theStruct.order"`, `"theStruct.flags"`, and so on. This creates a slight
>   dependency on the names of the fields in the source code, which over
>   time may get renamed, but the archiving keys cannot change if you want
>   to maintain compatibility.

---

A method that is very similar to `NSData` wrapping but uses `NSValue` (this is also discouraged, but will work for basic structs as well):

```
struct Paging {
    NSInteger currentPage;
    NSInteger totalResults;
    NSInteger resultsPerPage;
};

typedef struct Paging Paging;

- (void)someMeth {
    // Here `paging_struct` is a struct of type `Paging`:
    NSValue *pagingStructValue;
    // On its own line just for readability
    pagingStructValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&paging_struct
                                       objCType:@encode(Paging)];

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:pagingStructValue
                     forKey:@"paging"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

[`NSValue` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: unfortunately, this approach doesn't work for me on iOS 6+. i get: Attempt to insert non-property value ... of class 'NSConcreteValue'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Answer (score 0):

I made the less favourable decision to use struct in my iOS app. Now I am also facing this problem where I cannot save the struct (which contains about 30 variables) into NSUserDefaults easily.

After trying many solutions given in SO and other sites, it has not working well for me. So finally I decided to create a simple method to convert the struct into NSMutableDictionary.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)structToDictionary:(StructPictures) dat {


    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dat.bgOpacity],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.bgType], // 1= general,
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dat.glowAmt],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.textureNum],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.patternNum],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.patternType],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dat.patternHue],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:dat.textureSizer],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.stickerR],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.stickerG],
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:dat.stickerB]

                       , nil];


    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"bgOpacity",
                     @"bgType",
                     @"glowAmt",
                     @"textureNum",
                     @"patternNum",
                     @"patternType",
                     @"patternHue",
                     @"textureSizer",
                     @"stickerR",
                     @"stickerG",
                     @"stickerB",
                     nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *res = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

return res;
}
```

StructPictures is the name of my struct (custom).
Hope this give an alternative solution to saving struct into NSUserDefaults.