# What am I doing wrong with this NSMutableArray of structs in NSUserDefaults? "attempt to insert non-property list object"

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, struct, nsuserdefaults

I'm quite simply trying to save an `NSMutableArray`/`NSArray` of `struct`s in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
typedef struct {
    int key;
} provision;

provision p1;
p1.key = 4;
NSValue *p1Value = [NSValue value:&p1 withObjCType:@encode(provision)];

provision p2;
p2.key = 5;
NSValue *p2Value = [NSValue value:&p2 withObjCType:@encode(provision)];

NSMutableArray *provisions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[provisions addObject:p1Value];
[provisions addObject:p2Value];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:provisions forKey:@"Provisions"];
```

I followed [the guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8598613/998117) and store all the structs as `NSValue`. But that last line causes a runtime error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object (
>       "<04000000>",
>       "<05000000>"
>   ) for key Provisions'

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`,
>   `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of `NSData`.

The exception occurs because you try to store an `NSValue` object. 
To *store* the struct as `NSData`, use

```
NSData *p1data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&p1 length:sizeof(p1)];
```

and *extract* it from `NSData` with

```
[p1data getBytes:&p1 length:sizeof(p1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use a struct? If not, using a class instead of a struct would be better. Or you could even create a class to wrap your struct. To me, this would seem clearer (and therefore less prone to mistakes) than what you are try to do. Anyway, you can also do it as Martin R suggests.

**NOTE**: As MartinR points out in his comment to my answer, you also need NSData to add custom objects to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Objects of a custom class would also have to be archived as NSData because they cannot be stored in the user defaults.

Comment: @MartinR True; sorry.